# Setting the size of a div to 100% of browser window with bigger content in it

Tags: html, css, xhtml, svg

I have a problem with setting the height of the div:
I have 3 divs and svg element one in each other in such way:

```
<body>
  <div id="1">
    <div id="2">
      <div id="3">
        <svg></svg>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

(There are also other elements in div 1 and 2)

Assume that svg is very big (i.e. 2048x2048), I need that size of div3 (and this also would mean div2 and div1) to have size 100% of browser window (minus other elements and margins in uppers divs) - when a browser resize div also should. As the scg is bigger than div3 there should be a scrollbars in div3 (scrollbars should be in div3 not in whole browser window to scroll only content of div3 (the svg element) not of the whole browser content!).

I've already manage to make it works this way in width, but not in height,
when I set height of all elements except svg (also for body) to 100% as I found somewhere (also tried with min-height), then all divs are of height of svg and scrollbars apears on browser window, scrolling the whole page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any one interested in similiar case I managed to done this. I've resigined of using div3 (after all it wasnt needed) so the layout of page is smiliar to this:

```
<div id="1">
 something          
 <div id="2">
  <svg width='2048' height='2048' ></svg>
 </div>
 <div id="footer">something</div>
</div>
```

and css is:

```
body, html, {
padding : 0px;
margin : 0px;
width : 100%;
height : 100%;
} 
#nr2{
overflow: scroll;
position: absolute;
top: 10px; /* must be the height of everything above div */
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
bottom: 10px; /* must be the height of footer */
}
#footer{
height: 10px;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: see the new JSFiddle in my answer :)

Comment: yes, thats also ok, but this solution is without any js. It probably wont work on IE but IE does not support svg and Im making compltetly diffrent version for it

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
overflow:scroll;
```

To your CSS for div3.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/XHZWp/6//)

Comment: I've done this, but it's only makes scrollbars visible but not active, as the height of div3 is still 2048px, not the browser window height...

Comment: no, I need div3 to have size of browser window and have scrollbars to scroll the bigger svg in it. Example: div3 has margins set 10px from each size, user resized a browser  in such way that content window is 100x100, I want div3 to have size 80x80 and inside it I need scrollbars to scroll the svg (which is of size 2048x2048)

Comment: Ah, I didnt notice the link to JSFidle, yes, this is effect which I need but a problem is that here you have fixed width and height and Im looking for a way to do this for height set to size relative to browser window (i.e. 80%)